# How can I make a compiler choose flag-updating ARM instructions?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, flags

I am trying to make use of the CPSR flags when my code does arithmetic operations rather than using a series of if statements to check for overflow, carry, etc. in order to have smaller, faster code. A simple example is this addition operation:

```
int16_t a = 0x5000;
int16_t b = 0x4000;
int16_t result = a+b;
uint32_t flags = getFlags();
```

The code will need to run on various platforms, so getFlags() is the only part of the code that will be allowed to contain architecture-specific assembly.

```
inline uint32_t getFlags() {
    uint32_t flags = 0;
    asm (“mrs %0, cpsr”
        : “=r” (flags)
        :
        : );
    return flags;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn’t have any way of knowing that the addition operation in this example should be setting the flags, so it generates instructions similar to:

```
ldrsh r3, [r0]
ldrsh r4, [r1]
add r3, r3, r4
strh r3, [r2]
mrs r3, cpsr
```

In order for the CPSR to contain anything useful, I need the compiler to use adds instead of add (s suffix = update CPSR). Is there something I can change in my C code or possibly a compiler option that will cause it to choose flag-updating instructions? I can use either GCC or Clang.

Comment: This approach is very wrong. Modern compilers are not mechanical assembly-generating machines; you cannot expect they will crank out assembly instructions mirroring the source code, and that you can then go in and insert additional instructions.

Comment: *"The code will need to run on various platforms"* ... well, some CPUs do not have flags at all... just saying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot dictate which instructions the compiler will use. Such an approach is futile and is incompatible with the crucial optimization functions that compilers perform.

You can obtain portable overflow checking by using compiler builtins supported by both [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checked-arithmetic-builtins). For example, `__builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &c)` stores `a+b` in `c` and returns true if overflow occurred. (And it is type-generic; `a`, `b`, and `c` may be any integer types. Whether overflow occurs depends only on the values of `a` and `b` and the type of `c`.)

You can expect such builtins will participate in optimization, including using flag-updating instructions if they are suitable. (The GCC documentation explicitly states this.)

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of code can't work in a useful way because the compiler is free to rearrange code as it likes.  There isn't even a guarantee that the addition is the last flag-updating instruction before your `mrs` instruction runs.  If you want to get this right, put both the flag-setting addition and the `mrs` instruction in one `asm` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put the adds instruction into the asm statement since the getFlags() function is intended to be usable with several different arithmetic operations. I suppose I could make a separate function for each type of operation, though I was hoping it wouldn't have to come to that; I want to keep the platform-specific code as small as possible.

Comment: want to do it write you have to do it all in (real) assembly.

Comment: @superbowl I'm afraid that's what you have to do; one function for each arithmetic operation.  You might be able to use the preprocessor to reduce the amount of work you have to do for this.  If you like, I can write an example for you.